# MySQL Optimizer column relocation

Tags: mysql, indexing

I did some tests with INDEXES and their column placement order in the query.

Let's say I have this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `languages`
    WHERE
        `languages`.`active` = 1
        AND `languages`.`code` = 'nl_nl';
```

And 2 INDEXES:

- `code` (UNIQUE)
- `active`, `code` (has to do with ORDER BY)

The `EXPLAIN` says the possible keys are `code,index__active__code`, but weirdly enough it chose `code` as it's key.

Does this actually mean that the query optimizer will hustle around my WHERE fields to make them match one or more of my INDEXES better? So it will have made my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `languages`
WHERE
    `languages`.`code` = 'nl_nl'
    AND `languages`.`active` = 1
```

?

But then still, why didn't it choose to get the `active, code` INDEX? Is it because the matching type is `const`? Or is UNIQUE always favored?

**Update:**

Also this makes no sense to me:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `id`, `property_id` FROM (`modeldimensions`) WHERE `model_id` = 11040 && `active` = 1;
```

The possible keys are: `unique__model_id_property_id,index_model_id__active`

But yet it chose `unique__model_id_property_id`.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there could be some interaction with the PK.  There could be some datatype issues.  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mysql's optimizer will consider all indexes that are relevant for a query. It is going to choose the one it believes the most effective, but it can be mistaken.

Mysql and most other rdbms consider the cardinality (selectivity) of the index as a primary driver. You can check all index's cardinality in [information_schema.statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statistics-table.html) table or using [show index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html) command.

Cardinality is basically the number of unique values within an index. The higher the number of cardinality is, the better the index can be used to filter out records.

Unfortunately, cardinality is based on estimates only and may be inaccurate. Use `analyse table` command to update cardinality of an index if it is way off.

You can also use explicit [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) in your queries if you think that mysql makes the wrong choice about the indexes.

Comment: Yes I use `FORCE INDEX` mostly for MySQL failing to identify `ORDER BY` needs to use an `INDEX`. Do you have any knowledge of the `UNIQUE` indexes getting some kind of special treatment for the optimizer?

Comment: Unique indexes should have high cardinality, since they are unique. Therefore mysql should be more inclined to use it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. Indeed the table for the `modeldimensions` states 9030 cardinality on the UNIQUE key over a meager 184 on the NON-UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer sees that `(code)` is unique, so it will need to look at only one row.  Since `(active, code)` is not declared unique, the optimizer assumes that it might need to look at multiple rows.

On the other side of the coin is the way that InnoDB structures indexes.  (Is the table InnoDB?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, so we don't have to guess.)  There are two *secondary* keys to choose from.  (These are secondary, correct?)  It would seem more profitable to pick `(active, code)` in case no rows match, in which case there would be no need to reach into the data for `*`.  But people usually don't do `SELECT` to get nothing, so maybe that is a low priority.

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` might give you some more clues of the 'cost model' being used, hence why it decided on the 'wrong' index.